# HMM limiting distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Consider a hidden
markov model (HMM)
with two hidden states $A$ and $B$ and emission support $1$ and
$2$ fitted with initial state distribution
$$\lambda = [\begin{array}{cc} .7&.3\end{array}]$$
with a row-stochastic transition matrix
$$T = \left[\begin{array}{cc} .3&.7 \\ .2&.8\end{array}\right]$$
and row-stochastic emission matrix
$$O = \left[\begin{array}{cc} .2&.8 \\ .5&.5\end{array}\right].$$

I would like to find the limiting unconditional
distribution over the emission values,
i.e. the distribution over observations $o_t$ such that
$o_t = o_{t-1}.$
We can see that we can calculate
$o_1 = \lambda O$, although I am having difficulty find a calculation for
$o_t$ where $t > 1.$ Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably you have the relations $\lambda_t = \lambda_{t-1}T$ and $o_t = \lambda_t O$. Note that if the state itself converges, i.e. $\lambda_t \to \lambda^*$, then $\lambda_t O \to \lambda^* O = o^*$. Can you a) prove that $\lambda_t$ converges, and b) find the $\lambda^*$ it converges to? (Depending on your level, part a) may be out of syllabus for whatever course this comes from, but part b) certainly isn't :) ).

Comment: you need to diagonalize the transition matrix